# How do I render components generated from a string inside of a method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I pass in a string to a method called `parseMsg(msg)` which parses [item:5] into `<item :id="5"></item>`, then I store the parsed message inside of an array. When I loop through the array, the component isn't rendered.

This is part of a chat system, so not all parsed messages will contain [item:5]. The component should be rendered inline. For example, a user might type "Regular text blah blah [item:5] blah blah" and the component should be rendered at the correct position inside of the string.

How would I render this string to display the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need to do is make that chat bubble a component that gets dynamically rendered and you can put your `<item :id="5"></item>` component inside of it, try this,

```
<template>
  <div>
     <span :is="dynamiChatBubble">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    dynamiChatBubble () {
        return {
           template : '<div>You Messeage <item :id="5"></item> bla bla</div>'
        }
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

make sure you have registered the `item` component name globally. hope this helps